# Как обработать массив кнопок в Андроид

Tags: android, массивы, kotlin, button

Есть массив с кнопками. Как сделать смену цвета у кнопки(`background`) при нажатии на нее, не прописывая это действие для каждой кнопки. Повторное нажатие возвращает начальное состояние.
Поштучно код выглядит вот так

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var btArr = arrayListOf<Int>(R.id.bt1,R.id.bt2,R.id.bt3,R.id.bt4)
    var indexButton = 0   
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
var stat1 = 0
var stat2 = 0
var stat3 = 0
var stat4 = 0

fun changeColor(view: View) {
        indexButton = btArr.indexOf(view.id)
      when (view.id) {
            btArr[indexButton] -> {
                if (binding.bt1.isPressed) {
                    if (stat1 == 1) {
                        stat1 = 0 
                       binding.bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
                    } else {
                        stat1 = 1    
                   binding.bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange)
                    }
                }else
                if (binding.bt2.isPressed) {
                    if (stat2 == 1) {
                        stat2 = 0 
                       binding.bt2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
                    } else {
                        stat2 = 1    
                    binding.bt2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange)
                    }
                }else
                    if (binding.bt3.isPressed) {
                        if (stat3 == 1) {
                            stat3 = 0 
                           binding.bt3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
                        } else {
                            stat3 = 1 
                           binding.bt3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange)
                        }
                    }else
                        if (binding.bt4.isPressed) {
                            if (stat4 == 1) {
                                stat4 = 0   
                             binding.bt4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
                            } else {
                                stat4 = 1 
                               binding.bt4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange)
                            }
                        }
            }
         }
}
```

}

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Список кнопок определить? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html

Comment: массив кнопок определен fun buttonArr(){for (i in R.id.bt1..R.id.bt4){btArr.add(i)}} .  Мне надо в цикле произвести действие с кнопкой, которая была нажата.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что ID элементов можно вот так (R.id.bt1..R.id.bt4) итерировать? Это где-то задокументировано, что они идут по порядку? Не припомню такого.

Comment: запишу по другому 'var btArr = arrayListOf (R.id.bt1,R.id.bt2,R.id.bt3,R.id.bt4)' получу тот же массив. Или я чего-то не понял в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Так добавьте этот код в вопрос. Без него непонятно откуда начинать ответ. И опять же, это список идентификаторов, никак не кнопок, как вы пишете в вопросе.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja извините за некорректно заданный вопрос. Скорректировал. Сейчас код выглядит как сверху. Все работает, цвет при нажатии меняется. В проекте 30+кнопок и хотелось уменьшить количество строк кода.

Comment: Что-то я ни черта не понял... Вы хотите при клике по кнопке поменять её же цвет? На кой хрен тогда массивы и циклы? Есть слушатель нажатия - его вы задаёте кнопкам в любом случае и ему параметром передаётся именно та кнопка, которая нажата. Приводим этот параметр к нужному типу, если надо, и делаем через него с нажатой кнопкой что хотим

Comment: @woesss прав, весь этот огород у вас только ради того, чтобы помнить состояние кнопки. Храните состояние в самой кнопке. У любого UI элемента в Андроиде есть поле `tag`, в котором можно хранить что угодно. Либо `Map` заведите, где ключ `view.id`, а значение его состояние. И никаких массивов и длинных if-ов не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот примерно такой шаблон у меня получился.

```
// можно и не заполнять  
val states = mutableMapOf<Int, Boolean>(R.id.bt1 to false, R.id.bt2 to false, R.id.bt3 to false, R.id.bt4 to false)

fun changeColor(view: View) {
  val state = states[view.id] ?: false // начальное состояние при отсутствии
  (view as Button).setBackgroundResource(if (state) R.color.green else R.color.orange)
  states[view.id] = !state // тут заполнится
}
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для удобства и что бы убрать лишние элементы Вы можете поместить нужные вам кнопки внутрь какого либо ViewGroup, например RelativeLayout

```
    //цикл по всем view внутри ViewGroup
    for (v in findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.container_button)) {
        //проверяем что view это кнопка
        if (v is Button) {
            //действия с кнопкой
            v.isSelected = true
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Пожалуй самое сложное это понять вопрос. Скорее всего вы ищите что то вроде [color-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)

Например создаете `xml` файл `res/color/bg_button.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="#ffff0000"/> <!-- кнопка нажата-->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- выбрана-->
    <item android:drawable="#ff000000"/> <!-- по умолчанию -->
</selector>
```

И дальше меняем фон кнопки на bg_button

```
<Button
        ...
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        ...
 />
```

[Англ. stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18131705/7540461)

Comment: Хотелось бы без добавления доп элементов на активити. просто, есть массив 'fun buttonArr(){'
        for (i in R.id.bt1..R.id.bt4){
            btArr.add(i)}}' и есть слушатель для кнопки 'fun onClickSet(view: View){
          indexButton = buttonArr.indexOf(view.id)
            when (view.id) {
                buttonArr[indexButton] -> {
                  /// действие с нажатой кнопкой
                }}' я не могу понять, как допустим, поменять цвет у нажатой кнопки

Comment: @Leechkin дополнил ответ, так же почитайте про onfocuschangelistener и setOnTouchListener  - должно помочь

Comment: Таким образом я тоже делал, просто придется на каждую кнопку условие прописать, а их 30+. Может есть способ уменьшить количество строк?

Comment: Вариант с селектором может быть то что надо.

Comment: Вчера сделал через селектор, но так как пока учусь, прописал на каждую кнопку, и в место 
 'state_focused'  использовал  'state_selected'  чтобы цвет оставался измененным после нажатия